# TopPadding occurs when using XLPagerTabStrip and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, xlpagertabstrip

`SubViewController` (a child of `ViewController` and `IndicatorInfoProvider`) is added using `MainViewController` (a child of `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`) with `NavigationBar` added.

Padding does not occur even if you tap tabbutton, padding occurs on top when swipe.

animated gif

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRLg7.gif]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //tableview
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //動的に高さを変更
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 155
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    //indicator
    self.tableView.showIndicator()

    //loaddata
    loadData(page:0)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem.
Open your storyboard and select the `MainViewController`. In the Attribute Inspector deselect the checkbox '**Adjust scroll view insets**'

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a UITableViewController as a childViewController? This issue seems to happen in this case.

To fix this, you should be setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` and also having as childViewControllers only `UIViewControllers` with a `UITableView` inside, instead of `UITableViewController`.

Cheers